# CTLineGetImageBounds is a very extensive operation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-text

I'm working on a library that does some rich text abstraction using Core Text (https://github.com/pothibo/CMFramework), Everything is working and right now, I'm trying to find some major flaw in the code that could speed up the object at runtime.

Running the Time Profiler, I found that CTLineGetImageBounds is a *very* heavy operation, it takes twice as long to execute than CTLineDraw. However, I need to get the bounds of the line when I render the text so I cannot not use it.

Would anyone know a solution to speed up this process? You can see the whole code [here](https://github.com/pothibo/CMFramework/blob/master/CMKit/RichText/CMText.m#L272)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually found something. CTLineGetTypographicBounds yields the same result and doesn't require to actually have a CGContextRef.

Result can be seen [here](https://github.com/pothibo/CMFramework/blob/master/CMKit/RichText/CMText.m#L278)

Comment: I have a question about your CMFramework. I am using it to draw CMTextLabel in  MTableView(Cell).I'm wondering if I can somehow modify the drawRect: code to provide line breaking at word wrap mode using CoreText. `CTTypesetterSuggestLineBreak(typeSetter, range.location, CGRectGetWidth(rect) - offset);` Seems to cut off each line mid-word.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't saw that comment earlier. My apologies. As for your question, It's not a simple answer, the easiest fix would be to check for the latest char on the CTLine and change the length if it's in a middle of a word.